# Write csv to google cloud storage

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to understand how to write a multiple line csv file to google cloud storage. I'm just not following the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html?highlight=upload#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file)

Close to here: 
[Unable to read csv file uploaded on google cloud storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083960/unable-to-read-csv-file-uploaded-on-google-cloud-storage-bucket)

Example:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "<pathtomycredentials>"

a=[1,2,3]

b=['a','b','c']

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("<mybucketname>")

blob=bucket.blob("Hummingbirds/trainingdata.csv")

for eachrow in range(3):
    blob.upload_from_string(str(a[eachrow]) + "," + str(b[eachrow]))
```

That gets you a single line on google cloud storage

```
3,c
```

clearly it opened a new file each time and wrote the line.

Okay, how about adding a new line delim?

```
for eachrow in range(3):
    blob.upload_from_string(str(a[eachrow]) + "," + str(b[eachrow]) + "\n")
```

that adds the line break, but again writes from the beginning.

Can someone illustrate what the approach is? I could combine all my lines into one string, or write a temp file, but that seems very ugly.

Perhaps with open as file?

Comment: Where you able ot find a way to write into storage?

Comment: Please refer to my answer in below post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715977/how-to-write-to-xlsx-file-on-google-cloud-storage/54746884#54746884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `blob.upload_from_string(data)` method creates a new object whose contents are exactly the contents of the string `data`. It overwrites over existing objects rather than appending.

The easiest solution would be to write your whole CSV to a temporary file and then upload that file to GCS with the [`blob.upload_from_filename(filename)`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string) function.

Comment: if you have restrictions creating the file, IE your app is in app engine and you just cant, is there a way to actually write the file directly

Comment: upload_from_string stores it as a text file. Is it possible to transform it to a .csv?

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to below answer, hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
 data = [['Alex','Feb',10],['Bob','jan',12]]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Month','Age'])
 print df
```

**Output**

```
   Name Month  Age
0  Alex   Feb   10
1   Bob   jan   12
```

**Add a row**

```
row = ['Sally','Oct',15]
df.loc[len(df)] = row
print df
```

**output**

```
     Name Month  Age
 0   Alex   Feb   10
 1    Bob   jan   12
 2  Sally   Oct   15
```

**write/copy to GCP Bucket using gsutil**

```
  df.to_csv('text.csv', index = False)
 !gsutil cp 'text.csv' 'gs://BucketName/folderName/'
```

Python code (docs https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html )

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_bucket(bucket_name, blob_path, local_path):
    bucket = storage.Client().bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_path)
    blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)
    return blob.url

# method call
bucket_name = 'bucket-name' # do not give gs:// ,just bucket name
blob_path = 'path/folder name inside bucket'
local_path = 'local_machine_path_where_file_resides' #local file path
upload_to_bucket(bucket_name, blob_path, local_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from google.cloud import storage
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "<pathtomycredentials>"

a=[1,2,3]

b=['a','b','c']

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("<mybucketname>")

blob=bucket.blob("Hummingbirds/trainingdata.csv")

# build up the complete csv string
csv_string_to_upload = ''

for eachrow in range(3):
    # add the lines
    csv_string_to_upload = csv_string_to_upload + str(a[eachrow]) + ',' + b[eachrow] + '\n'

# upload the complete csv string
blob.upload_from_string(
            data=csv_string_to_upload,
            content_type='text/csv'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this post after I have encountered the exact same problem.
After a lot of struggles, I found that the best solution for me is to upload the .csv file as bytes. Here is how I did that:

```
new_csv_filename = csv_path + "report_" + start_date_str + "-" + end_date_str + 
".csv"
df.to_csv(new_csv_filename, index=False)
# upload the file to the storage
blob = bucket.blob(new_csv_filename)
with open(new_csv_filename, 'rb') as f:  # here we open the file with read bytes option
    blob.upload_from_file(f)   # upload from file is now uploading the file as bytes
blob.make_public()
# generate a download url and return it
return blob.public_url
```